Problem with serialization and deserialization in Polenter SharpSerializer
I've created my own class, which imitates dictionary. The main difference is my class allows on adding null to keys.
The problem is serialization with Polenter SharpSerializer, because this nuget doesn't interpretate this generic like dictionary.
I've tried to create own serialization (and deserialization) setting class, but it didn't work. I don't know, where is the problem.
Click here to see code of my class.

Don't post code as a link to a word document, include it in the question. Also you haven't shown your serialization code.

Might you please [edit] your question to include your code in the question itself (ideally as a [mcve]), rather than as an external link?  From [ask]: Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem... If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to ... then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.
